# How do I get the count of nil and not nil values from a list of specific attributes from a table in a Rails 5 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

Rails 5 app, User model is set up with Devise

I have a User model that was created with the Devise gem. I want to get the count of specific columns in the model that are nil and also not nil. For example, I am using this to get the count of ALL of the columns:

Nil: `<%= user.attributes.values.count { |v| v.nil? } %>`

Not Nil: `<%= user.attributes.values.count { |v| !v.nil? } %>`

But, I only want to find the count for certain attributes. I only want

- name
- cel
- city
- state

If I create a model method like this

```
def profile_attributes
  [:name, :cel, :city, :state]
end
```

Then in my view:
`= volunteer.profile_attributes.count` => 4

Now, if `city` and `state` are `nil` I would want => 2

How do I get this to work?

Comment: you are right. my typo.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was actually pretty obvious. I probably didn't explain myself well in the question. The way to do this is just to add select. So, you would have the following:

```
<% User.select(:name, :cel, :city, :state).each do |user| %>
  Nil count
  <%= user.attributes.values.count { |v| v.nil? } %>

  Not nil count
  <%= user.attributes.values.count { |v| !v.nil? } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Do you fill comfortable doing SQL queries in your view? I'm pretty sure you can do something better in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, given a `volunteer` as `User` object having `profile_attributes` method:

```rb
# not nil
(volunteer.profile_attributes.select { |attr| !volunteer.send(attr).nil? }).count
# nil
(volunteer.profile_attributes.select { |attr| volunteer.send(attr).nil? }).count
```